# How to determine whether expression is positive or negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, absolute-value

Given expressions $|x - 3 + y|$ and $|x + 3 + y|$ how can I determine, whether are those positive or negative, and determine their value in the intervals of:

1. $y < -x - 3$
2. $y \in [-x - 3, 3 - x)$
3. $y > 3 - x$

---

**Edit:** I forget to add, that there are two another conditons $x \geq 3$ and $y < 0$.

Comment: All of them are nonnegative due to the definition of absolute value.

Comment: $|x|<1 \implies -1<x<1$. for the first one, see $y<-x-3\implies y+x+3<0$ and $y>3-x \implies x-3+y>0$